# How to setup controller to respond to a specific object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set up my controller so it responds to the "first" video record in the database so it will skip the validations in the model.

```
video.rb
  validates :link, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT, unless: :skip_video_validation
  before_create :uid_link_match, unless: :skip_video_validation
  before_update :uid_link_match, unless: :skip_video_validation
  attr_accessor :skip_video_validation
end
```

How to set up in controller so that I can get first video to skip these validations.

```
def update
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    if @video == @video[0]
    @video.skip_video_validation = true
      if @video.update_attributes(video_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Video updated!'
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
    ...
  end
```

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong and why.

Comment: Why do you want to disable validations for the first video in your application? What is your definition of first - by creation date, by the number of votes, first viewed?

Comment: If I get you correctly, you can use `Video.first` instead of `@video[0]`

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `if @video == @video[0]` would be `false` for almost every well-formed objects in the universe.

Comment: The first video for a specific user. So @user.videos[0]. This video gets created when the user is created then never gets deleted. It is more just a dumby entry so I can update just one attribute not all so need to skip validations.

Comment: @musdasobwa. Why is that for? I have used comparisons like this elsewhere in my app and it has evaluated to true.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Simple mistake wasnt thinking just had to change a few lines :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full code should be in controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  if @video == @user.videos[0]
  @video.skip_video_validation = true
    if @video.update_attributes(video_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Video updated!'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  else
...
```

end